# "Configuration object that does not match the API schema" using webpack node api

Tags: node.js, webpack

I get an

> Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>    - configuration should be an object.

When I try to require a webpack config via the [webpack node api](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/) using the following lines:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpack(webpackConfig);
```

I can build the very same webpack.config.js from within the same folder using the npm cli

```
webpack
```

What could be the problem here?

The webpack config looks like that:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = function(env) {
    return {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
        output: {
            filename: "./bundle.js",
            path: env!==undefined&&('output_path' in env)? env.output_path : path.resolve(__dirname, "bin")
        },
        externals: [
            "angular",
            "uuid",
            {
                "lodash": {
                    commonjs: "lodash",
                    amd: "lodash",
                    root: "_" // indicates global variable
                }
            },
            {
                "jquery": {
                    root: "$",
                    amd: "jquery",
                    commonjs: 'jquery'
                }
            },
            {
                "jquery-ui": {
                    amd: "jquery-ui",
                    commonjs: 'jquery-ui'
                }
            },
            {
                "Slick": {
                    root: "Slick",
                    amd: "Slick",
                    commonjs: 'Slick'
                }
            }
        ],
        devtool: 'source-map',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js'],
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: "html-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /.*\.less$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use:[ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ],
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'module.css', disable: false, allChunks: true })
        ]
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Just solved the issue myself:

My webpack.config.js is not an object, but a function - i.e., the error string is pretty accurate. So I just needed to change the snippet to

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js')();
webpack(webpackConfig);
```

to make it work.